# JAVASCRIPT: what does "this" keyword refer to in the Prototype pattern below (Phaser framework)

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

```
//HTML code
<!doctype html>
    <head>
    <script src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/boot.js"></script>
    <style>body{margin:0}</style>
    <script>    

    var letsgo = function() {
    var game = new Phaser.Game(320, 480, Phaser.CANVAS, "game");
    game.state.add("Boot",boot);
    game.state.start("Boot");
    };
    letsgo();

    </script></head><body></body>
</html>

******boot.js***** 
var boot = function(game){};

boot.prototype = {     //prototype pattern
    preload: function(){
    this.game.load.image("loading","assets/loading.png");       
    },
    create: function(){ // this code is not important
        this.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
        this.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
        this.scale.setScreenSize();
    }
}
```

What does `this` refer to in `this.game.load.image("loading","assets/loading.png");`? Without the prototype it refers to `boot` object. But with the prototype pattern it takes a different object value. I am trying to find out what that object value is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pseudoclassical instantiation pattern.  (You can tell because it's using this and .prototype.)  So "this" refers to its instance.

[This](http://www.willvillanueva.com/an-introduction-to-pseudoclassical-instantiation-patterns-and-subclassing-in-javascript/) is a very good blog on the topic.

In short, pseudoclassical instantiation is done by placing a `new` keyword.  You may have seen something like this before: `var instance = new Constructor(params);`?

What the new keyword does is on runtime add two lines of code into whatever code exists already.  i.e.,

```
var Person = function(name, age) {
  // new keyword adds this line:
  // this = Object.create(Person.prototype);
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;

  // it also adds this line:
  // return this;
}
```

Functions that are kept separate from attributes in this pattern because they do not change from instance to instance.  So in this case (and to mirror your example) we would have:

```
Person.prototype.greet = function() {
  console.log(this.name);
};
// .... more functions here.
```

Or, as in your example, they are overwriting the prototype object entirely by doing this:

```
Person.prototype = {
  greet : function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  },
  ...
}
```

**So, in short**
"this" will refer to whatever instance is created.
`var bob = new Person("Bob", 40);`
for bob, this refers to the object which has the properties name = "Bob", age = 40.

We can create multiple instances:
`var sally = new Person("Sally", 34);`
now for sally, "this" points to the object which has the properties name = "Sally", age = 34.

Both of these can coexist, and we don't have to worry about how they're used later because "this" keeps track of a given instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand what you described. But i'm still confused because nothing is actually instantiated. There is no instance, and no instance will be created for this particular code. And "this" does not point to boot. So if there is no instance and it doesn't point to boot, then what does "this" point to? Or am I just seeing this the wrong way?

Comment: You're using a Framework, so they are abstracting the pseudoclassical instantiation for you.  That is how it is working.  If you dig through the [docs](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Game.html#add), you will see in the source code on line [535](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/v2.3.0/src/core/Game.js) that add uses the new keyword to instantiate a [GameObjectFactory](https://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.GameObjectFactory.html) based on the parameter given.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I will be studying this more. I tried to upvote your answer but apparently I don't have enough points. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The token "this" in your snippet will refer to any object that is created with the "new" keyword against the constructor "boot".

So for example, if elsewhere in the script there is a line like:

```js
var myBoot = new boot(someGame);
```

myBoot will be to what "this" refers.